# How to perform different actions when thread takes different amount of time to execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

There exists a rest service which performs some calculations and prints the results in an excel file, which is returned, as response.. As data is increasing, we want to implement following behaviour. If file  is ready within 3 sec , return excel else, send a text message.. And file is later mailed to user.

Any suggestions, how can we implement this functionality, in Java ??

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Future` with timeout:

```
public String getExel() {
     CompletableFuture<String> getter = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "result");
     try {
        return getter().get(3, TimeUnits.SECONDS);
     } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
       // invoke email sending
       getter.thenAcceptAsync(result -> sendEmail(result));

       // I will send you email later
       return "XXx to indicate you will send him later";
     }
}

public void sendEmail(String resultFromGetExel) {

}
```

Comment: Lets see, from main method, We created a future that would collect data, prepare excel sheet... In main, we are wait for 3 sec, this future to returns excel..and excel is returned. All fine... But, If we exceed 3 sec, we want to return a string  from main method and continue with processing excel and later send a mail.. How can we do that? The created thread returns excels or mails it.??

Comment: The getter has 3s timeout. If it finish in 3s you can use it to return your excel. Else it throw timeoutexception, you can handle your email sending in that catch

Comment: In case, the thread completes after 10 seconds, and we have already handled Time out exception, and returned a string to user that file would be mailed later.. If catch is already used to returned the string message, how and when will we send the mail, and also, how will we check, if thread is  complete?

Comment: Generally you use `thenAcceptAsync` to invoke the second path. Read my edited answer